# Spring Data Pageable with custom query, returns zero objects if limit is greater than number of elements

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an API exposed which reads data from DB using custom query and returns object. Am using Pageable object in my custom query.

```
Page<Employee> findByOptionalParams(@Param("name") List<String> name
            Pageable page);
```

I have around 1011 records in my DB. when I fire API with,

http://localhost:8080/employee?offset=1010&limit=1

Iam getting one object record response, but if i fire

http://localhost:8080/employee?offset=1010&limit=2. Iam getting zero record. Ideally it should return the one object which is present. Can anyone let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Offset` mean `PageNumber` and `limit` mean `pageSize` .

Comment: Then how http://localhost:8080/employee?offset=0&limit=5 would work?
offset 0 means, 0pageSize? it should not return element?

Comment: Also if i fire http://localhost:8080/symbols?offset=1010&limit=1. It should give 1010 element right?

Comment: Yes ! If you have record in dB.

Comment: No, it's not working in that way. Iam still getting 1 record for
http://localhost:8080/symbols?offset=1010&limit=1

Comment: you have 1010 record in db?

Comment: Also, can you kindly let me know if i have 1011 records in DB, how I can get 1010 records in one page and another 1 record on the second page? I think my question is real time common use case.

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan What's your final query create?

Comment: Sorry, Syed, I didn't get your question.

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan kindly , send me a query !

Comment: SELECT * from Employee where name = :name;

I appreciate your response, but I think the discussion is getting prolonged.

Comment: offset means pageNumber and limit means page size. You interchanges i think and that created confusion

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan Ohh Sorry! you're right its confused me ,